# How to continue the page scroll once the div scroll is ended

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a HTML page with two different divs, the second div is sticked to the bottom unless the first div scrolls to the bottom of the page. I would like start scrolling the page once the first div completes its scroll. How can I do this?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.container-2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #474752;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="container">
  Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
  Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
  <h1>
  Container 2 title
  </h1>
  Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I would like start scrolling the page once the first div completes its scroll." Do you mean you want container-2 to scroll after container scroll ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a third div as placeholder. It has a height like 'container-2' and is hidden when 'container-2' begins to scroll. Since the padding from 'container-2' results in a height of 8rem and scrolling back causes a flickering, i deactivated the padding for the **Working example:**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var containersHeight = $('.container').outerHeight() + $('.container-3').outerHeight();
  if (Math.floor($(window).scrollTop()) >= Math.floor($('.container').offset().top + containersHeight - window.innerHeight)) {
    $('.container-2').css({
      'position': 'static',
      'height': 'auto'
    });
    $('.container-3').hide();
  } else {
    $('.container-2').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'height': '5rem'
    });
    $('.container-3').show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: #474752;
  position: fixed;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container-3 {
  height: 5rem;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overflow">
  <div class="container">
    Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum
    ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
    sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus.
    Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque
    in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum
    ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <h1>
      Container 2 title
    </h1>
    Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur aliquet quam id
    dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
  </div>
  <div class="container-3"></div>
</div>
```

If you don't want a third div you can also achieve this by setting a padding bottom similar to the height of 'container-2'. But for that you have to get the height of the first container outside of the function, which could have eventually negative effects when resizing the window while scrolling (for example changing the screen orientation on mobiles).

**Working example:**

```js
var containersHeight = $('.container').outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  if (Math.floor($(window).scrollTop()) >= Math.floor($('.container').offset().top + containersHeight - window.innerHeight)) {
    $('.container-2').css({
      'position': 'static',
      'height': 'auto'
    });
    $('.container').css('padding-bottom', '0');
  } else {
    $('.container-2').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'height': '5rem'
    });
    $('.container').css('padding-bottom', '5rem');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.container-2 {
  background-color: #474752;
  position: fixed;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overflow">
  <div class="container">
    Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum
    ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
    sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus.
    Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque
    in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum
    ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipiscing elit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <h1>
      Container 2 title
    </h1>
    Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur aliquet quam id
    dui posuere blandit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Way to do without the third container? @biberman

Answer (score 0):

Edited!
Use the same plugin like the sample you showed,

> Check Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/q4vdczLh/

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  licenseKey: 'YOUR KEY HERE',
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange'],
});
```

Plugin: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-or-bigger-sections

Comment: Sorry @yeyene I want the scroll to continue I don't want two different scrolls for the containers. I don't want the container 2 to scroll independently it should be part of the main scroll but it should also be fixed to the bottom of the page until the first container scroll completes.

Comment: Basically I wanted to continue with the page scroll once the div scroll is ended.

Comment: But your container-2 has overflow hidden, and you still want it to scroll and fixed at the bottom at the same time?

Comment: I keep `overflow: hidden` just to hide the body text other than the title in container-2. Initially the title of the container-2 is shown and it is fixed to the bottom. Once the top container is scrolled and reached to it bottom the container-2 will reveal the content and start scrolling with the page.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the parallax effect, like this? 
Demo: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: Similar to the first section [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html#firstPage).

Comment: check edited answer, use the same plugin, but modified not to use as full page, by using extra class 'fp-auto-height'

Comment: "*Similar to the first section here*" @Benjamin this was not what your question asks for...